# transaction cannot complete using JtaTransactionManager, while using JpaTransactionManager works fine

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, jta

I have a big problem with using JTA and Spring Data (1.9.2). My project works fine when I'm using JpaTransactionManager. I have also tried JdbcTemplate (no Spring Data) with JTA, that also works fine. I have tried OpenJPA (2.2.1) and Hibernate (4.2.8), both Jetty and Websphere Liberty server. They all fails using JTA and works fine using JPA Transaction Manager. The datasource is XA capable, and currently Derby Embedded. Springframework is v4.2.1

This is my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAKSSTATUS")
public class SaksStatus implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID") 
        private String id;

        public SaksStatus() {};

        public SaksStatus(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

}
```

My DAO

```
public interface SaksStatusDao extends JpaRepository<SaksStatus, String> {

}
```

My transaction

```
@Transactional
public void test() {
    logger.info("deleting before testing ");
    saksStatusDao.deleteAll();
    logger.info("save...");
    saksStatusDao.save(new SaksStatus("100"));
    logger.info("save OK");
    logger.info("result: {}", saksStatusDao.findAll());
    logger.info("removing ...");
    saksStatusDao.deleteAll();
    logger.info("flush ...");
    saksStatusDao.flush();
}
```

My application context :

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/derbyEmbedded" />

<context:component-scan base-package="no.klp.saksstatus.dao" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

<jpa:repositories base-package="no.klp.saksstatus.dao"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="no.klp.saksstatus.dao.entities" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"></bean>
<bean class="no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService"/>
```

My persistence file

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceunit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>no.klp.saksstatus.dao.entities.SaksStatus</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My enhancer plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>no/klp/saksstatus/dao/entities/**/*.class</includes>
        <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
        <persistenceXmlFile>${basedir}/META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXmlFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enhancer</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

So when executing my transaction I've got his log :

```
2016-02-02 13:34:52,391 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:367 - Creating new transaction with name [no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService.test]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-02-02 13:34:52,423 saksstatus-service INFO  no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService:30 - deleting before testing 
2016-02-02 13:34:52,429 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:351 - Adding transactional method 'deleteAll' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-02-02 13:34:52,429 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:250 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2016-02-02 13:34:52,430 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:476 - Participating in existing transaction
2016-02-02 13:34:52,456 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:272 - Opening JPA EntityManager
2016-02-02 13:34:52,457 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:290 - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[err] 1409  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 26992656> executing prepstmnt 1533150303 SELECT t0.ID FROM SAKSSTATUS t0
[err] 1410  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 26992656> [0 ms] spent
2016-02-02 13:34:52,674 saksstatus-service INFO  no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService:32 - save...
2016-02-02 13:34:52,675 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:351 - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-02-02 13:34:52,675 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:476 - Participating in existing transaction
[err] 1525  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 1984659730> executing prepstmnt 715039869 SELECT t0.ID FROM SAKSSTATUS t0 WHERE t0.ID = ? [params=?]
[err] 1526  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 1984659730> [0 ms] spent
2016-02-02 13:34:52,778 saksstatus-service INFO  no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService:34 - save OK
2016-02-02 13:34:52,779 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:351 - Adding transactional method 'findAll' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
2016-02-02 13:34:52,779 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:476 - Participating in existing transaction
[err] 1539  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 977455988> executing prepstmnt 1441490501 SELECT t0.ID FROM SAKSSTATUS t0
[err] 1539  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 977455988> [0 ms] spent
2016-02-02 13:34:52,781 saksstatus-service INFO  no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService:35 - result: []
2016-02-02 13:34:52,781 saksstatus-service INFO  no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService:36 - removing ...
2016-02-02 13:34:52,781 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:476 - Participating in existing transaction
[err] 1541  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 1721406628> executing prepstmnt 174725407 SELECT t0.ID FROM SAKSSTATUS t0
[err] 1541  default  TRACE  [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 925948525, conn 1721406628> [0 ms] spent
2016-02-02 13:34:52,783 saksstatus-service INFO  no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService:38 - flush ...
2016-02-02 13:34:52,783 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:351 - Adding transactional method 'flush' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-02-02 13:34:52,784 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:476 - Participating in existing transaction
2016-02-02 13:34:52,785 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:858 - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
2016-02-02 13:34:52,785 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:1072 - Setting JTA transaction rollback-only
2016-02-02 13:34:52,786 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:250 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2016-02-02 13:34:52,790 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435 - Closing JPA EntityManager
2016-02-02 13:34:52,802 saksstatus-service DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager:851 - Initiating transaction rollback
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible:413'
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.; nested exception is <openjpa-2.2.1-r422266:1396819 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:122)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.flush(Unknown Source)
    at no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService.test(SaksStatusService.java:39)
    at no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fcbe12b7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at no.klp.saksstatus.services.SaksStatusService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$db202906.test(<generated>)
    at no.klp.saksstatus.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.1-r422266:1396819 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assertActiveTransaction(BrokerImpl.java:4694)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.assertActiveTransaction(DelegatingBroker.java:1386)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:662)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:486)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 23 more
```

One difference from using JPA transaction manager, is the only SELECT statments are logged. The INSERT statement is not executed (when using JPA Transaction Manager, they where all logged).

The save entry (saksStatusDao.save(new SaksStatus("100"));) should create an INSERT. And to the end a DELETE should be executed.

Everything seems very fine, but the last flush() is starting the rollback, please give me some advice to solve this. Have been struggeling with this for a month now ....

Using JPA transaction manager is not a option as I want to use JTA and allowCustomIsolationLevels to utilize UNCOMITTED_READ.

/Bjørn-Willy Arntzen, Oslo, Norway